# ASP.NET HttpContext exclusive values for each user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I am creating a project using ASP.NET MVC 3. So now I need to pass some data that need to be available into the entire project.

I am using IHttpModule and set values in the HttpContext items. My doubt is, the values I add into HttpContext items will be exclusive values for each user session or will be the same?

```
public class BaseHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = application.Context;
        context.Items[Key] = "value1";          
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thos items only persist a single request, so therefore they are scoped and exclusive to a particular user insofar as a single user is making that request.

You might want to try something like this

```
var application = (HttpApplication)sender; 
application.Application["domain"] = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

Those items only survive that *single page request*. The `Context` serves a single request.